# fosuserbundle access user object from controller symfony2

Tags: object, fosuserbundle

am new on Symfony2 and using fosuserbundle to manage my users

how do i access the user object from my controller. I need to get the user_id to build a directory which would look like this : uploads/{user_id}/...

Answer (score 1):

You can access the user object in a controller this way:

```
$this->getUser();
```

So if you need the user id, you can use the getter method:

```
$this->getUser()->getId();
```